# ... had seen those people. "I must have met..."

Tags: plot

In your opinion, should the last two sentences be joined together by a linking word (for instance: so he whispered, 'I must have...') or should I leave them as two separate sentences?

Alex looked at the photograph in the newspaper and thought the people in it seemed very familiar. The picture was part of an article which dealt with a project carried out by a well-known company. At first sight, he couldn't remember where he had seen those people. 'I must have met them recently,' he whispered.

Comment: Both options are bad. Search online for "filter words in writing" –– lots of advice how to avoid them.

Comment: While there may be ways to make your paragraph more compelling, there's nothing wrong with it as written. It doesn't require a linking word though: that would probably qualify as bad.